# Import class from Python file in another folder -- not a child folder

Tags: python

Here is the structure of my directory:

```
MyFolder
   -run.py
SecondFolder
   -class.py
```

What I have attempted is adding the directory path to `sys.path` within the `run.py` file and this will work only occasionally (not sure why):

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/Users/.../SecondFolder/class.py')
from class import Connection
```

How can I ensure the module is always loaded? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Answer (score 1):

If SecondFolder doesn't have to be in the same location as MyFolder, you can add it to the python site-packages.

From there, you can import it as so:

```
from SecondFolder.class import Connection
```